# Post Prestashop Form with Ajax - Tools::getValue()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello I wanna save a form into prestashop database with ajax, but I encounter some difficulties. Let me show you my try.
HTML Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" class="">
    <textarea name="question_content" row="4" class="form-field"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="saveQuestion" id="question_ajax_save" class="button-standard">Frage abschicken</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#question_ajax_save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var question = $("input[name=question_content]").val();
    if (question !==''){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseUri + 'modules/genzo_questions/ajax.php',
            data: {
                save_question: 1,
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

                response = $.parseJSON(response);

                if (response.status === false){
                    // Do something
                }
                else {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP Bridge:

```
if (Tools::getValue('save_question')==1) {
    echo json_encode($genzo_question->ajaxSaveQuestion());
}
```

In my method ajaxSaveQuestion() I want to use **Tools::getValue('question_content')**. But it's empty. Why is this? I could send it with "data:" but in my method I need Tools:getValue('id_product') too, which is also empty.

In short: How can I use Tools::getValue('') with Ajax Post?

Comment: the only data you are passing in the ajax post is 'save_question', not the 'question_content'. add it to the data in the post. or was this a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo. Is this the only solution? My hope was, that I could get this data (question_content) just in php method. Do I need to send it with ajax?

Comment: if you are creating the Post, you need to add question_content: question to the data in it.

Comment: Thanks Sir, you helped me a lot! I wonder one thing... My data looks now like this: data: {
                    save_question: 1,
                    question_content: question,
                    id_product: id_product
                }
Why do I get correct id_product, without defining anything? I should note that this form is sent on a product page...

Comment: the best way is to check if there is already another hidden field with that value. if not, set a hidden input in you form like question_id_product. then get that value like the question_content.

Comment: You are right! There was already a hidden field with this value! Thanks again. I will close now the question.

Comment: @EmanuelSchiendorfer `id_product` variable is available because it's set by the [product template](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl#L713).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add this in your ajax.php file :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../config/config.inc.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../init.php';
```

Then you can use prestashop functions like : Tools::getValue('')

I think that you forgot to add question_content in your code :

```
$("#question_ajax_save").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var question = $("input[name=question_content]").val();
    if (question !==''){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseUri + 'modules/genzo_questions/ajax.php',
            data: {
                save_question: 1,
                question_content: question
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

                response = $.parseJSON(response);

                if (response.status === false){
                    // Do something
                }
                else {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```